# Format text in QTextBrowser in PyQT

Tags: formatting, pyqt, qtextbrowser

I want to write a text in QTextBrowser in PyQt. I have something like this:

```
    for line in working_data:
        word = line.split(";")
        self.ui.textBrowser.append("{:30}{:>30}".format(word[1], word[2]))
```

With this I get something like (left and right alignment):

```
ID      Value
123      10,00
1234      20,00
1      330,00
12345      1,00
```

I would like to have it like this:

```
ID       Value
123      10,00
1234     20,00
1       330,00
12345     1,00
```

How to achieve that? I looked [here](https://pyformat.info/) and tried `{:30}'.format('test')` and `{:>30}'.format('test')` for right align case, but it would'n reserve 30 places for a first word.

Comment: What is the font you use in the text browser? You have to use a mono-spaced font, like as courier, to ensure that all characters have the same width.

Comment: Thank you! The line `self.ui.textBrowser.setFontFamily("monospace")` did it.